# ZF2 layout form set input filters and validation

Tags: forms, layout, get, zend-framework2

For my application in Zend Framework 2 I created a 'search form' in my layout.phtml.
I did this in my Application module by adding the search form as an variable.

(Form location Application/src/Application/Form/SearchForm.php)

Application/Module.php:

```
public function setFormToView($e)
    {
        $searchForm = new SearchForm();
        $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->setVariables(array(
            'searchForm' => $searchForm,
        ));
   }
```

The form directs to an Action in another module, here I want to handle what to do with
the incoming query.

MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/MyModuleController.php

```
public function dataAction()
    {
        $form   = new SearchForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

        $website = $this->params()->fromQuery('search');

        return array('searchForm', $form);
    }
```

Getting the query 'search' is no problem, it works well. No I want to use my inputFilter I created under 'Application/src/Application/Model/Search.php'.

I tried to add this in my 'dataAction()' but no results, but I even can't change the submit value as I tried in my example above.

How do I set this in the right way in this situation? Or else, what is the right situation to handle a search form in layout.phtml.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: Are you displaying your form inside layout.phtml only?
If so then the form you are setting in the action is ignored, as that is passing the form to the "content" view file for the action and not layout.phtml

Comment: Thanks, solved this already a while ago with setting my own validator :)